# Jquery simplyScroll visible controls on mouse hover on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needs to get Jquery simplyScroll plugging controls visible only on mouse scroller I did something but it's not working

```
$(function() { //on DOM ready
    $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
        speed: 7
    });
});
```

Looking for some one's help to get this worked.

Thanks

here I am posting my css file I can't find the exact line you mentioned please help.

```
/*
 * simplyScroll 1.0.3 - a scroll-tastic jQuery plugin
 *
 * http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll
 * http://logicbox.net/blog/simplyscroll-jquery-plugin
 * http://plugins.jquery.com/project/simplyScroll
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Will Kelly - http://logicbox.net
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt)
 * and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
 *
 * Last revised: 03/07/2009 21:13
 *
 */

/* Default/Master classes 

Example markup format (for horizontal scroller)
Note all DIVs are generated and should not be hard-coded

<div class="your-custom-class simply-scroll-container">
    <div class="simply-scroll-btn simply-scroll-btn-left"></div>
    <div class="simply-scroll-btn simply-scroll-btn-right"></div>
    <div class="simply-scroll-clip">
        <ul class="simply-scroll-list">
            <li>...</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


*/

a{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

a:hover{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#000;
}

.simply-scroll-container { /* Container DIV - automatically generated */
    position: relative;
}



    .simply-scroll-clip { /* Clip DIV - automatically generated */
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .simply-scroll-list { /* UL/OL/DIV - the element that simplyScroll is inited on */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        .simply-scroll-list li {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .simply-scroll-list li img {
            border: none;
            display: block;
        }

    .simply-scroll-btn {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url(buttons.png);
        width: 20px;
        height: 250px;
        z-index:3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .simply-scroll-btn-left {
        left: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-position: 0 -250px;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-left.disabled {
        background-position: 0 0 !important;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-left:hover {
        background-position: 0 -250px;
    }

    .simply-scroll-btn-right {
        right: -20px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-position: 84px -250px;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-right.disabled {
        background-position: 84px 0 !important;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-right:hover {
        background-position: 84px -250px;
    }

    .simply-scroll-btn-up {
        right: 6px;
        top: 6px;
        background-position: -126px -44px;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-up.disabled {
        background-position: -126px 0 !important;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-up:hover {
        background-position: -126px -88px;
    }

    .simply-scroll-btn-down {
        right: 6px;
        bottom: 6px;
        background-position: -42px -44px;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-down.disabled {
        background-position: -42px 0 !important;
    }
    .simply-scroll-btn-down:hover {
        background-position: -42px -88px;
    }

/* Custom class modifications - override classees

.simply-scroll is default

*/

.simply-scroll { /* Customisable base class for style override DIV */
    width: 1100px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-clip {
        width: 1100px;
        height: 250px;
        left:20px;
    }

        .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list {}

        .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 250px;
        }
        .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li img {}

    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn {}

    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-left {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-left.disabled {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-left:hover {}

    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-right {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-right.disabled {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-right:hover {}

    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-up {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-up.disabled {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-up:hover {}

    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-down {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-down.disabled {}
    .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-down:hover {}



/* Vertical scroller example */

.vert { /* wider than clip to position buttons to side */
    width: 340px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

    .vert .simply-scroll-clip {
        width: 290px;
        height: 400px;
    }

        .vert .simply-scroll-list {}

        .vert .simply-scroll-list li {
            width: 290px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .vert .simply-scroll-list li img {}

    .vert .simply-scroll-btn {}

    .vert .simply-scroll-btn-up { /* modified btn pos */
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .vert .simply-scroll-btn-up.disabled {}
    .vert .simply-scroll-btn-up:hover {}

    .vert .simply-scroll-btn-down { /* modified btn pos */
        right: 0;
        top: 52px;
    }
    .vert .simply-scroll-btn-down.disabled {}
    .vert .simply-scroll-btn-down:hover {}

    /* NOTE left-right classes wouldn't be needed on vertical scroller */

/* Flickr example 

Images created from a data source use simpler format i.e.

<div>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    ...
</div>

*/

.flickr {
    width: 576px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

    .flickr .simply-scroll-clip {
        width: 576px;
        height: 180px;
    }

        .flickr .simply-scroll-list img {
            float: left;
            border: none;
            display: block;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS to achieve this. Add those lines to your stylesheet:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ZmxK4/)**

```
/* default display is none */
.simply-scroll-container .simply-scroll-btn-up,
.simply-scroll-container .simply-scroll-btn-down,
.simply-scroll-container .simply-scroll-btn-left,
.simply-scroll-container .simply-scroll-btn-right { 
    display: none; 
}

/* when hovering the container, show the up, down, left and right buttons */
.simply-scroll-container:hover .simply-scroll-btn-up,
.simply-scroll-container:hover .simply-scroll-btn-down,
.simply-scroll-container:hover .simply-scroll-btn-left,
.simply-scroll-container:hover .simply-scroll-btn-right { 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I have posted my css code but I am unable to find that line can you help me ?

Comment: You have to add those lines to your css

Comment: Do i have to modify anything on the css file instead of adding it ? i have added but something wrong

Comment: one more thing that i am using few scrollers on the same page...is there any issue with it ?

Comment: I did not realize you are using the horizontal one. I have added the "left" and "right" buttons as well and updated the demo. Normally it should be ok for several scrollers.